# Radio button formatting in IE8 (not displaying correctly)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem with getting my radio buttons laid out (and checkboxes) correctly in IE8 .. Firefox, Chrome, Opera all working however ..

Here is a screenshot of the problem

[image: IE8 problem]

The code is below:

```css
.row input (line 471) {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: 0pt;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0pt;
  margin-left: 0pt;
}
.row label (line 479) {
  float: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
div.panes label (line 70) {
  font-size: 95%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 150%;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="AdditionalResponses_0__Response" id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_Label">Single answer</label>
<div class="row " id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response">
  <input id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_one" name="AdditionalResponses[0].Response" type="radio" value="one" />
  <label for="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_one" id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_one_Label">one</label>
  <input id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_two" name="AdditionalResponses[0].Response" type="radio" value="two" />
  <label for="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_two" id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_two_Label">two</label>
  <input id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_three" name="AdditionalResponses[0].Response" type="radio" value="three" />
  <label for="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_three" id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_three_Label">three</label>
  <input id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_four" name="AdditionalResponses[0].Response" type="radio" value="four" />
  <label for="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_four" id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_four_Label">four</label>
</div>
```

Sorry for the one long line, but that's how I got it through the source..

Comment: inserting the image didn't work .. but here is a link

http://i46.tinypic.com/245j7o5.gif

Comment: how dow you want it to look ? because i think it shows wrong in all browsers ... (*different wrong than IE though ..*)

Comment: I wrapped your code in a <form> tag and it displays on a single line for me in IE8. Am I missing something?

Comment: it shows fine in all the other browser (that's not the only CSS code that exists in the page)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the height or float from .row input.
Avoid adjusting the line-height if you can, as well.

Comment: doing that just puts everything in block format with the labels on top of the radio buttons ..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another case of IE Stepdown: [Preventing Menu Stepdown](http://css-tricks.com/prevent-menu-stepdown/)

Comment: and the row input and the row label ... doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to align them vertically or horizontally?

If vertically, add this to your css

```
.row label {
    display: block;  
}
```

and change your markup so that your inputs are wrapped by the labels. You wouldn't have to use the for="" attribute this way.

```
<label>
    <input id="AdditionalResponses_0__Response_one" name="AdditionalResponses[0].Response" type="radio" value="one" />
    one
</label>
```

If horizontally, add

```
.row input, .row label {
    float: left;  
    display: block;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but - did you try the clear property?
in your case the value would be left i think
[w3 source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control)

Comment: so I added the clear:both  and this is what I came up with .. 

http://tinypic.com/r/72f4tw/6

Comment: ok wer almost there now you can either style your labels to re-align them correctly or you could put your inputs inside their respective labels - which is valid (in the right order - text last)

Comment: What style would you suggest? I've tried fiddling with padding, and line height but neither really do the trick ..

Comment: did you try putting the inputs inside the labels firt? // <label for="example"><input type="radio" id="example" />one</label> // if you wanna style instead you should try playing with inline/block and margin/padding/line-height // maybe you should clear the labels too

Comment: I haven't tried the label around the input - only because of the way it's being written in .net

I did add a padding-top: 5px to Label though and it seemed to work (in IE) however it pushed off everything in Chrome and FFox - doh!

Comment: well now you just need to conditional comments to isolate IE css or use css hacks to target a specific version of IE // http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html // using <br /> is another solution // problem solved? accept my answer :)